# call jquery upload function only when form validation is successful

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

This is my first post here.  I have been looking for the answer to this for a while now and have looked at several posts in order to try and understand the syntax.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to get this to work.

I have a file upload form and I am using the following script in conjunction with the [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) to modify my status bar during file upload.

```
<script>
(function() {    
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');
    $('#create_playlist').ajaxForm({
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            if (percentComplete == 100) {
                status.html('Processing <img src="../images/loader.gif" />');
            } else {
                status.html('Uploading...');
            }
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html('Done! <img src="../images/success.png" />');
            window.location.reload(true);
    //      status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
})();
</script>
```

I am also using the following script of the same page to validate my form using the [jquery validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#create_playlist").validate({
            rules: {

                    newfile: {
                            required: true,
                            accept: "text/plain" 
                    },

            },

            errorElement: "span",   
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            },   


            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Both of these scripts work well independently. However, if the second script shows validation errors, it does not currently prevent the first script from running.

What I would like to do is call the first script only when validation in the second script is successful.  I believe that the fist script should be called instead of "form.submit();" in the following code from the second script.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {             
    form.submit();
}
```

After attempts to place the first script inside the script handler of the second script or call the first script as a function, I still have not been successful.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per [jQuery Validate documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> `submitHandler` (default: native form submit):
>
> Type: Function()
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated**.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create_playlist").validate({
            rules: {
                newfile: {
                    required: true,
                    accept: "text/plain" 
                }
            },
            errorElement: "span",   
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },   
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                //form.submit(); <-- remove this... it's redundant because the plugin will submit when valid
                var bar = $('.bar');
                var percent = $('.percent');
                var status = $('#status');
                form.ajaxForm({
                    // your ajaxForm code here
                });
                return false;
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, you are missing a `return false;` event, to prevent the form from submitting. You need a conditional statement to verify the first function functions, if it does, call the second else display a message and return false.

Comment: Hi dihakz, Thankyou for your response.

If there is an error with the submitted form, the validation plugin already displays errors and prevents the form from being submitted.  The problem is that the file upload script is still triggered by the submit button in the form regardless of the validate plugin preventing the submit.

Comment: is there a way to call the function in the file upload script once validation is successful?  I think that it should be called instead of `form.submit();` as this is only run once validation is successful.